# Returning a pointer from a function

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

This is in reference to this question: *[Why is a pointer to pointer needed to allocate memory in this function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625869/why-pointer-to-pointer-is-needed-to-allocate-memory-in-function)*

The answer to the question explained why this didn't work:

```
void three(int * p)
{
    p = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    *p = 3;
}

void main()
{
    int *p = 0;
    three(p);
    printf("%d", *p);
}
```

... but this works:

```
void three(int ** p)
{
    *p = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    **p = 3;
}

void main()
{
    int *p = 0;
    three(&p);
    printf("%d", *p);
}
```

This also works, by returning a pointer from the function. Why is that?

```
int* three(int * p)
{
    p = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    *p = 3;
    return p;
}

void main()
{
    int *p = 0;
    p = three(p);
    printf("%d", *p);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int* three(int * p) 
    {
        p = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
        *p=3;
        return p;
    }
```

Because here you're returning a *copy* of the pointer `p` and this pointer now points to valid memory, which contains the value 3.

You originally passed in a *copy* of your `p` as an argument, so you're not changing the one you passed in, but a copy. Then you return that copy, and assign it.

From the comment, which is a very valid point, this will also work just as well:

```
 int* three() 
        {
           //no need to pass anything in. Just return it.
            int * p = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
            *p=3;
            return p;
        }
```

Comment: Passing the pointer is pointless here as malloc will overwrite it anyway.

Comment: @KingsIndian: I'd say, rather: allocating memory here is pointless, as a pointer is passed anyway. :P

Comment: @netcoder: that depends if the caller is required to allocate.

Comment: @TonyTheLion: Right. It's a question of ownership. I rarely return allocated pointers, I prefer the have the caller allocate and free the memory it needs.

Comment: @netcoder Regardless of ownership, my previous is still valid. i.e. You don't have pass a pointer when you are going to overwrite it :)

Comment: So basically instead of modifying the pointer's value directly, you modify the value of a copy of said pointer and you return said copy after modifying it's value and assign returned value to the original pointer. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

They're completely different (and if you truly understand why the first works, you'd see there's no connection).

By returning, you're not attempting to modify the already existing pointer from inside the function. You're just returning a new pointer, and assigning its value outside.

Answer (score 0):

Look at it as a question of scope.

In `main()` you have a pointer `p`.

```
int *p = 0;
```

`p` in main is set to NULL. When you make a call to the three function passing it p:

```
three(p);
```

You are passing a pointer to NULL. What happens to it is outside the scope of `main()`. `main()` does not know, nor does it care what happens. `main()` only cares about its copy of `p`, which at this point is still set to NULL.
Unless I reassign `p` within the scope of `main()` (including handing off the address of `p`), `p` is still just a pointer pointing to NULL.

If I give you this code:

```
void main()     
{
     int *p = 0;
     funcX(p);
     printf("%d",*p);     
}
```

You can tell me definitively what is going to happen (Segmentation fault) without ever knowing what `funcX()` does because we're passing a copy of the pointer to this function, but a copy doesn't affect the original.

But if I give you this code:

```
void main()     
{
     int *p = 0;
     funcX(&p);
     printf("%d",*p);     
}
```

You can't tell me what will happen unless you know what `funcX()` is doing.

That make sense?